# Deploying ASP.NET Core ap to Azure: dotnet restore fails

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-web-app-service

Trying to deploy a asp.net mvc core app to Azure WebApp but it fails when trying to do `dotnet restore` with the following error

```
error MSB4057: The target "_GenerateRestoreGraphProjectEntry" does not exist in the project.
```

In Azure console

```
dotnet --version
1.0.0-preview3-004056
```

and on my machine

```
dotnet --version
1.0.0-preview4-004233
```

Perhaps I need to set the `global.json` to target a specific framework if that differs from what I have on my machine.

(this is not part of the question, just spitting my guts out :)
This day hasn't been a good day being a .net developer (either on Mac or Windows) since none of them work at the moment after VS 17 RC2 update on .csproj, various msbuild issues and lastly IIS Express authentication stopped working (redirect loop during sign in)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately changing `global.json` won't work in your case :(

Azure currently only have these `dotnet cli versions`

```
1.0.0-preview1-002702
1.0.0-preview2.1-003155
1.0.0-preview2-003121
1.0.0-preview2-003131
1.0.0-preview2-003156
1.0.0-preview2-1-003177
1.0.0-preview3-004056
```

based on what you described, it looks like you were able to do `dotnet restore` locally on your dev machine, but not in Azure

I suspect that this is becuase `1.0.0-preview3-004056` does not have the latest **msbuild**:

```
D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk\1.0.0-preview3-004056>dotnet.exe MSBuild.dll
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.1.0.0
```

I don't have your "**1.0.0-preview4-004233**", but compare to [latest dotnet release on github](https://github.com/dotnet/cli):

```
C:\Downloads\dotnet-dev-win-x64.latest>dotnet.exe sdk\1.0.0-preview5-004269\MSBuild.dll
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.1.458.808
```

its not hard to see that **Azure is missing couple bug fixes of msbuild** (15.1.458.808 > 15.1.0.0)

I would suggest that you change your `global.json` to version `1.0.0-preview3-004056`, and try to `dotnet restore` your project locally, **if it does fail with the same error message, then it would confirm my theory**...and the solution is either wait until Azure to catch up or upload your own `dotnet cli` to Azure

**[Edit]**

Azure now has `1.0.0-preview4-004233`

Comment: if you need help to get `1.0.0-preview3-004056`, submit an issue to https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues I can further assist you :)

Comment: Back from christmas holiday! Changing to `004056` works fine locally.. Navigated to root of solution and did `restore` and then `build`. Is there any guide on how to upload a more recent cli to Azure Web App?

Comment: Resorted to VS publish option for time beeing. WIll follow the issue at kudu for further details! Thanks